# Why is the delete function not working in my jsp file?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have created a table to display data and there is a checkbox next to each of the data. I want to create a function where if the user click the checkbox of that data and press the delete button, the data will be remove from the table and the database. I have came up with the code but it doesn't remove the data. What is the problem with my code ?

[Display on Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMyul.png)

**HTML**

```
   <%
        String id = request.getParameter("hiddenID");
        String sql1="";
        {
            sql1 = "select * from exercise1";
            PreparedStatement pstmt1=conn.prepareStatement(sql1);   
            ResultSet rs1 = pstmt1.executeQuery();
            while(rs1.next()){


            String arm      = rs1.getString("Arm");
            String time1    = rs1.getString("Time1");

            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td style = 'width: 20%'>");
            out.println(arm);
            out.println("</td>");
            out.println("<td style = 'width: 5%'>");
            out.println(time1);
            out.println("</td>");
        %>


        <td style="width: 5%"><input class="mychkbox" type="checkbox"
        value="<%=id%>" form="multipleDele" name="DeleteChkbox" /></td> 

        <%
            out.println("</tr>");
                }   
            conn.close();
                }
        %>
```

**This is my delete.jsp file**

```
    <%
    String[] id = request.getParameterValues("DeleteChkbox");
    int count=0;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Step 2: Define Connection URL
        String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/medicloud?user=root&password=root";
        // Step 3: Establish connection to URL
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);

        if (id != null)
        {
        for(int i=0;i<id.length;i++){
        String sqlStr = "DELETE from exercise1 WHERE id=?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
        pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id[i]));
        //pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id[i]));
        int rec=pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if (rec==1)
            count++;
        }
        }


            //System.out.println(functions);
%>
    <form action="exercise.jsp" method="post">
        <label><%=count%> record(s) deleted!!</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Return" name="ReturnBtn" />
    </form>
<%

        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e);
    }
%>
```

Comment: Just a tip, you only need to prepare the statement once, then you can reuse it for each of the required deletes - much better for speed and resource usage.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Jason

Comment: Everything works fine, except the data cannot be removed.

Comment: I have tried adding it in my loop. But still, i cant delete the row on my webpage. There is no errors produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` you are writing to the checkbox value is not coming from the database results. It is being retrieved in the JSP from a request parameter:

```
String id = request.getParameter("hiddenID");
```

... and then being written to every checkbox field:

```
<input class="mychkbox" type="checkbox" value="<%=id%>" form="multipleDele" name="DeleteChkbox" />
```

**You aren't writing a different id for each checkbox.**

As such, it probably is not the id of any of the database records, and therefore none of them are being deleted.

You should be reading the `id` of each record in your while loop when building the HTML.

I suspect you need something like this:

```
<input class="mychkbox" type="checkbox" value="<%=rs1.getString("id")%>" form="multipleDele" name="DeleteChkbox" />
```

Comment: If i don't include the "[]" , it has error in the for loop. (id.length is the error)

Comment: Edited to try to clarify my description. The problem is in your 'HTML' file. You are writing the same id to every checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Your image has three columns: arm exercises, number of times and action. The `DeleteChkboox` field will only tell you if the field is selected or not for a particular row. You need to get the ids that have been selected for deletion. Unchecked checkboxes will not show up in an array of checkboxes so your form has to take this into account. It needs to look something like

```
<form action = "...">
    <input type="submit" value="delete">
    <input type="submit" value="assign">
    <table>
    <c:forEach items="${ records }" var="r">
        <tr>
            <td>
                ${ r.exercise }
            </td>
            <td>
                ${ r.times }
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="${ r.id }" name="userAction">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
</form>
```

Then you need to change your jsp so that you get the ids of the selected rows. Change the jsp part that iterates your ids to

```
<%
    // get array of ids
    String[] ids = request.getParameterValues("userAction");

    int count=0;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Step 2: Define Connection URL
        String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/medicloud?user=root&password=root";
        // Step 3: Establish connection to URL
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);

        if (ids != null) {
            for(int i=0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                String sqlStr = "DELETE from exercise1 WHERE id=?";
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);

                pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(ids[i]));

                int rec=pstmt.executeUpdate();
                if (rec==1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

%>
```

That aside, it's generally not the best of ideas to be running sql updates in jsps if you can help it. Consider moving this logic to a controller class and using the jsp layer for presentation only.

EDIT

As per your comment "it's not working", instead of looking at this particular problem (why doesn't the code you wrote remove the data) you have to look at the bigger picture: what is the problem you are trying to accomplish?

It looks something like this, in plain English:

1. Show a user a set of records
2. Allow the user to mark the records they'd like to delete (array of checkboxes); allow the user to submit this information (the record ids)
3. Process (delete) the submitted ids

**Step 1**

Iterate over a list of records in jsp, inside a `<form>` element
For each record, create a checkbox whose value is that record's id

**Step 2**

Add a delete button allowing the user to submit the form of ids

**Step 3**

Process the submitted information: get the list of ids submitted in the request, iterate over it and delete the records one by one

Which step are you stuck on?

Comment: I have problem testing out your code. "Booleanrequest" could not be resolved. Can you help me out?

Comment: Sorry there were some typos. Check again.

Comment: I am stuck at step 3. I could not delete the records one by one.

Comment: Debug your controller. Take a look at the request parameters. Make a note of what's missing. Try to make it work for just one record first. Then try to make it work for multiple records.

Comment: what do you mean by controller? sorry, i am new to this.